# Javascript Reference Outer Object From Inner Object

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Okay, I see a few references given for Java, but not javascript ( which hopefully you know is completely different ). So here's the code specific :

```
function Sandbox() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        , callback = args.pop()
        , modules = (args[0] && typeof args[0] === 'string' ? args : args[0])
        , i;

    if (!(this instanceof Sandbox)) {
        return new Sandbox(modules, callback);
    }

    if (!modules || modules[0] === '*') {
        modules = [];
        for (i in Sandbox.modules) {
            if (Sandbox.modules.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                modules.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
        Sandbox.modules[modules[i]](this);
    }

    this.core = {
        'exp': {
            'classParser': function (name) {
                return (new RegExp("(^| )" + name + "( |$)"));
            },
            'getParser': /^(#|\.)?([\w\-]+)$/
        },
        'typeOf': typeOf,
        'hasOwnProperty': function (obj, prop) {
            return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
        },
        'forEach': function (arr, fn, scope) {
            scope = scope || config.win;
            for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
                fn.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
            }
        }
    };

    this.config = {
        'win' : win,
        'doc' : doc
    };

    callback(this);
}
```

How do I access this.config.win from within this.core.forEach? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the body of the Sandbox() function, like this：

```
var self = this;
```

and then;

```
self.config.win
```

in the core section when the context-sensitive 'this' has changed

Comment: nitpicking, but that's not what a closure is.

Comment: Much obliged, I tried that everywhere except the Sandbox function ( long day at work probably didn't help ).

Comment: I've seen `that` used a lot. `var that = this;`.

Comment: you're right nickf. I was originally writing something else ('var Sandbox = function (){...return function() {} }()') however, realized it wasn't necessary. thanks for the assist

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a function expression however this requires that you define `this.config` before `this.core`.  This prevents you from having to use a local variable.  Note however this captures the value instead of referencing it so if you assign a new value to `config` it will have no effect on `forEach`.  You can however still change `config.win` since the object was not cloned.  This kind of behavior can be subtle and cause bugs if used incorrectly.

With all that said it is best to use `var self = this;` as suggested by Jonathan.  This is however another way to do it and has situations where it is useful.

```
this.config = {
    'win' : "win",
    'doc' : "doc"
};

this.core = {
    'exp': {
        'classParser': function (name) {
            return (new RegExp("(^| )" + name + "( |$)"));
        },
        'getParser': /^(#|\.)?([\w\-]+)$/
    },
    'typeOf': typeOf,
    'hasOwnProperty': function (obj, prop) {
        return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);
    },
    'forEach': (function(config){
        function (arr, fn, scope) {
            scope = scope || config.win;
            for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
                fn.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
            }
        }
    })(this.config)
}
```

Comment: Although it wouldn't be useful for what I am doing, rated up since I appreciate the alternative way to handle it ( never know it may come in handy ). Much obliged to the answer sir.